# Existence of unique periodic solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to prove or disprove that the ODE
 $$ 
y'(x) =  y( x )^9 + ( 1+\sin( x)) y(x) +\cos(x) =0
$$
 has the unique periodic solution? 
PS. Its fieldplot done with Maple
[image]

Comment: What happens if $y(2\pi) = y(0)?$ What happens if it does not?

Comment: Anyway, three more items. What happens if $y(0) \geq 2?$ What happens if $y(0) \leq -2?$ Finally, given two solutions $y_1(x), y_2(x)$ with $y_1(0) < y_2(0),$ what can you say about the size of $y_2(x) - y_1(x),$ especially at $x = 2 \pi?$

Comment: @WillJagy: Presumably you are hinting at a continuity argument. How does one show that there is a solution for $x \in [0,2 \pi]$ (I mean one that doesn't blow up) for the various initial $y(0)$?

Comment: @copper.hat, in the absolute worst case you need to reverse time; this would be necessary for $y' = y^2$ if we could not get explicit solutions. I once made up an ODE where the only pleasant solution was the ratio of the CDF to the PDF (something lie that, anyway) for the Gaussian normal distribution in statistics. All the other solutions did weird shit, although not all blew up. Anyway, reversing time takes soltuions that may split apart from each other badly to ones that come together.

Comment: @copper.hat, anyway, I suspect that there is some interval for $y(0)$ such that we can show that solutions with initial values there get closer together. I might have worked out some of that, but when an OP posts and then runs away, i generally stop wasting my time. This could work for $|y| < 1$ for example, not sure. That is, maybe if $|y(0)| < 1,$ perhaps $|y| < 1$ forever. Maybe $1/3$ would work better than $1$

Comment: @copper.hat, not sure reversing time helps here. It has been too long. Still, if $y<1$ positive, $y^9 < y .$

Comment: @WillJagy: Thank for the comments! I like these sorts of problems. I think I have an approach that works, instead of looking for a solution that intersects $x=2 \pi$, I only need to see where the solution intersects a large rectangle in $y-x$ space, and then your initial suggestions (appropriately adapted) seem to work (ie, where the solution 'hits' the large rectangle is a continuous function of the initial condition. At least, its something for me to play with...

Comment: @copper.hat sounds good

Comment: @copper.hat, back with groceries. If we take solutions with $y_2(2\pi) = 10^9$ and  $y_1(2\pi) = -10^9$ and run time backwards, we get values $y_1(0) < y_2(0)$ such that any initial $y(0)$ between them gives a solution that cannot blow up  by $2 \pi,$ as this is first order Lipschitz and solutions cannot cross.  After this observation, it is just a matter of negotiating the price. Note, as in $y' = y^3 - y,$ there may easily be multiple periodic solutions (for this toy problem actually constant).

Comment: @copper.hat, done with shower; $10^9$ is unnecessary and a bit misleading; just take $y_2(2 \pi) = 2, y_1(2 \pi) = -2,$ run time backwards, you get $-2 < y_1(0) < y_2(0) < 2.$

Comment: @WillJagy: Excuse my pace; it is obvious that the backwards ODE will exist for the interval $[0,2 \pi]$?

Comment: @copper.hat, yes, if $y \geq 2,$ the forward ODE has $y' > 0.$ Opposite for $y \leq -2.$ So the backwards ODE's are coming together to an extent, but cannot cross, so both stay between $-2$ and $2.$ Nothing would be given if we considered solutions one at a time; having two unable to cross is critical.

Comment: @WillJagy: Nice. Thanks.